# How do I create a object set with a key?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object

I have the following variable like so:

```
const uid = 1;
const name = 'New York';
const latitude = x;
const longitude = y;
```

I'm trying to create the following structure:

```
{ 1: { name: 'New York', latitude: x, longitude: y}}
```

So I can put it in a dictionary like so, where the keys are the uid:

```
cities: {
     1: {
          name: 'New York',
          latitude: x,
          longitude: y
         },
     2: {
          name: 'Copenhagen,
          latitude: x,
          longitude: y
        }
}
```

How do you do it? I've tried the following:

```
 const obj = { id { name, latitude, longitude }};
```

Comment: Change `id` to `[id]:`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-z5lusp?file=index.js ... check whether this is what you expect